# Recordset does not support adseek

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, adodb, vba

I am planning to use MS Access as the database for my program. I have no knowledge of MS Access and at this point I am doing trial and error and tons of research about it. On my research I have found out that Seek method can quickly locate the row that matches the specified values. However it seems like the provider "Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0" does not support adSeek method. I found this out using the code below.

```
Sub Test3()


Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'Set a connection
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

'Set connection string
sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database21.accdb" & ";"
Cn.Open ConnectionString:=sConnString

'open recordset
rs.Index = "ID"
rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rs.Open "Table1", Cn

'Message if the recordset supports adSeek
MsgBox rs.Supports(adSeek)



Cn.Close

End Sub
```

Given that I have no experience in any database or MS access, I don't know if conclusion is correct or I'm just missing something. Can I use the Seek method using MS Access?

Comment: Provider should not limit Seek. CursorLocation does. But in your code it should work. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj250027.aspx but your question is interesting

Comment: I've done some research, and the answer by Alex K seems valid. Note that you also need to use the _index name_, not the _column name_. By default, the index name of the primary key is _PrimaryKey_

Answer (score 1):

> [**Seek**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/seek-method): This method can only be used when the Recordset object has been opened with a CommandTypeEnum value of adCmdTableDirect.

So you need to change to:

```
rs.Open "Table1", Cn, , , CommandTypeEnum.adCmdTableDirect
```

Personally I have rarely found seek/find/filter to be particularly useful, executing an SQL SELECT statement is the most perfomant way to fetch records.